# AWS API Not reporting correct number of items

Tags: json, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

Very simply, using DynamoDB to scan items. When I go to the AWS console (https://us-east-1.console.aws.amazon.com/dynamodbv2/home) and look at the number of items for a specific date, the view is three items.

[image: AWS CONSOLE]

Then, using a simple Python script, scanning the table for items. However, the result set is two, not three as is seen in the DynamoDB table.

[image: Python]

[image: Output]

The question is, how is it possible for the GUI console to be right, but the most basic of scans using the exact same filter conditions be returning one less item?

Answer (score 1):

The GUI is paginating and your code isn’t. Look at LastEvaluatedKey in the scan call return value and use it to pull the next page.

Comment: This is correct. But the odd part is that for 2 years it was working fine. Then, all of a sudden a few weeks ago it stopped working where 10% of the time it would return 1 or two items and 90% of the time it would return all of the items.

Comment: Perhaps you loaded some new data in your table which was placed so as to be earlier in the scan order than the data you're filtering for.